How to force JavaScript fetch api to request page in desktop mode?
I use the JavaScript fetch api to download json files from Reddit's public json endpoints.  Recently, Reddit has made their json endpoints respond differently based on whether the browser is in desktop mode or mobile mode. If the browser is in mobile mode, my app now receives bogus data from Reddit in most cases, whereas in desktop mode my app receives correct data.
How can I force the fetch() call to make the request in desktop mode?

It probably has heuristics that check the User-Agent. You'll need to send a desktop user agent.

You can do something like the following:


// Replace this value to your api address.
var Address = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
// Set the options for the `fetch` api.
var Options =
{
   headers:
   {
      // Replace this value to any desktop user agent.
      'User-Agent': 'Put any desktop agent here',
      
      // Or replace any other header that can make the
      // Reddit api return the contents for desktop.
   },
   mode: 'no-cors', // Change this according to your needs.
};

fetch(Address, Options).then
(
   Response => console.log('Response:', Response),
   Issue => console.log('Some issue happened:', Issue?.message ?? Issue),
);




Why mode: 'no-cors'?

Just for it to work on the snippet. If not the fetch fails...

Instead of a runnable wrong snippet, you could post a non-runnable correct snippet.

no-cors is always wrong if your intention is to get data from a server.

This is exactly what I needed.  I am using infinite-scroll, which already takes a fetchOptions structure, so this ended up being a very easy fix.  Thanks!

Er, scratch that. I thought this was exactly what I needed, unfortunately CORS strikes again as Reddit (ab)uses it to not allow the User-Agent to be changed.  CORS is the most annoying roadblock I've ever encountered in web development.  Still, +1 because I did not know about the headers option.
